# css does not apply to data from load();

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have been working in Jquery mobile and have been trying some samples and I have been stuck now.
I have a db which stores some data and i have been retrieving through php and printing the data like this:

`$("li").click(function(){$("#content").load('get_items.php?div='+index);
});`

I am passing a variable index to the db to retrieve details from db from a php script like this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
                    mysql_select_db("somedbname") or die(mysql_error());    

                    $category_id=$_GET['div'];

                    $data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id=".$category_id) or die(mysql_error());
                    $output[] = '<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="plus">'; 
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
                    {   

                        $output[] = '<li>';
                        $output[] = '<a href="">'.$row['item_name'].': Rs.'.$row['price'].'/-</a>';
                        $output[] = '<a href="order.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">do something</a>';
                        $output[] = '</li>';

                    }
                    $output[] = '</ul>';
                    echo join('',$output);
```

I wanted to to display the items in a split button list in the page,

but the code is showing a simple un-ordered list with bullets.

I tried with the jquery apis `.css()` and `.addClass()` methods but could not get it working.

can any body tell me what could be the solution to get the split button list?

thank you

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the PHP or MySQL. Can you make a testcase in HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Comment: You need to show the final HTML that is outputted and what css styles you are applying to the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should trigger the create event. Something like this:

```
$("li").click(function(){$("#content").load('get_items.php?div='+index, function(){
  $("#content").trigger('create');
}); });
```

check this out: http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html